# Unity Sprite into texture streched

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, sprite

I'm making a Doom-styled game and I'm having trouble with the enemy sprites.
I'm using a panel to display the sprites and then I made this code to turn the sprite into a texture:

```
//ignore the array of sprites, pretend there's only one sprite
      public Sprite[] spr;
         // Update is called once per frame
         void Start()
         {
             var texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
             // set the pixel values
             texture = spr[0].texture;
             // Apply all SetPixel calls
             texture.Apply();
     
             // connect texture to material of GameObject this script is attached to
             panel.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
         }
```

Problem:

[image: Sprite looks warped, stretched]

My solution so far has been to go into the settings of this new texture and changing from Opaque to Cutout. But how do I do that in the script?

Comment: How exactly is your `var texture` related to the `spr[0].texture` ? I don't understand why you create a new `var texture = new Texture2D ....` and then you do `texture = spr[0].texture;` and thereby lose the just created textrue reference .... did you rather mean `spr[0].texture = texture;` ? Could you post your actual code?

Comment: and with `changing from Opaque to Cutout` do you mean the texture or (what I suspect) rather the **material** ?

Comment: For the later see the bottom of this page [Unity Manual "Rendering Mode" -> "Changing the Rendering Mode using a script"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterRenderingMode.html)